# How to display textview dynamic value for localization of android

Tags: java, android, string, localization

Hello friends I want to integrate multiple languages in my application so I made multiple values folder for different languages.
Now my question is how can I display my dynamic textview value which comes from my web api which is string value. But How can I display language as per my choice from application. Below I have mentioned my code. Please help me. Thanks!

**Main.java**

```
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
   textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText("My custom text which comes from web api");

   }
```

Comment: I think it should work if your just use R.string from res folder

Comment: Nik Myers : ya i know it is work but it is works only for lable textview , can i use dynamic text value for that if yes than how?

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic value in TextView with localization in resource folder.
You can localize text by with country code and language code.
like:

```
res/values-en/string.xml
res/values-hi/string.xml
res/values-IN-gu/string.xml
```

[Read More](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the language localisation from the android framework using strings.xml, create one strings.xml for each language inside the proper values folder. Refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) to do this.

From server you can get the text key which you define in stings.xml then in your textview set this key and android will automagically show the proper localised text.